# How to get A-Z and 0-9 from a string?

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

How do I get "Lrumipsm1" from "Lörum ipsäm 1!"?

So what I need is to only get a-z and 0-9 from a string, using php.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

E.g. by using a regular expression ([pcre](http://docs.php.net/pcre)) and replacing all characters that are not within the class of "acceptable" characters by ''.

```
$in = "Lörum ipsäm 1!";
$result = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '', $in);
echo $result;
```

see also: http://docs.php.net/preg_replace

edit:
`[a-z0-9]` is the class of all characters a....z and 0...9
`[^...]` negates a class, i.e. `[^a-z0-9]` contains all characters that are *not* within a...z0...9
+ is a quantifier with the meaning "1 or more times", `[^a-z0-9]+` matches one or more (consecutive) characters that are not within a...z0..9.
The option `i` makes the pattern case-insensitive, i.e. [a-z] also matches A...Z

Answer (score 0):

you can do this also

```
$in = "Lörum ipsäm 1!";
$result = preg_replace('/[^[:alnum:]]/i', '', $in);
echo $result;
```